# Rails with Devise user confirmation link not confirming accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

This hasn't been a problem in the past, but for some reason when I click the link in Devise confirmation emails for my Rails app, it goes to the site but doesn't confirm the account.

My app is hosted on Heroku and I'm sending the emails through Mandrill. I just switched my app to HTTPS yesterday, so maybe that could be it? Here's the template itself for confirmation_instructions.html.erb:

```
<h3>Welcome to AnyMarket!</h3>

<p>Please click to link below to confirm your account and get started:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

And in Production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'anymarket.co'} 


    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :port => '587',
        :address => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
        :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
        :password => ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'],
        :domain => 'heroku.com',
        :authentication => :plain
        }

    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

In user.rb:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

Also I have overridden the RegistrationsController to add some custom logic. Here it is:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:after_inactive_sign_up_path_for]

    def new 
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html
        end
    end

    def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
                set_flash_message :onboard, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
                set_flash_message :onboard, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(user)
        respond_to do |format|
             format.html {render :action => "/"}
    end
  end

    private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :school, :provider, :uid)
  end

  def account_update_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar, :braintree_customer_id)
  end

end
```

Maybe it could also have something to do with my create action in the registrationscontroller? I'm really not sure. The emails send find and the confirmation token shows up in the URL briefly while it's loading.

Here are the logs I get after clicking submit on the sign up form:

```
Started POST "/users" for 98.245.3.223 at 2014-09-10 05:19:43 +0000                                                         
2014-09-10T05:19:43.542630+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                                                             
2014-09-10T05:19:43.542639+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to sfds@anymarket.co (82.0ms)                                                                                     
2014-09-10T05:19:43.564646+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://www.anymarket.co/                                                                                     
2014-09-10T05:19:43.564786+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 214ms (ActiveRecord: 21.2ms)                                                                         
2014-09-10T05:19:43.350891+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML                                                                        
2014-09-10T05:19:43.350917+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TsjutBJu4kLW3bdlszJp0gAo1snW/GG47lNsvzC8LJE=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"TF
DSFD", "last_name"=>"FDSDSF", "email"=>"SFDS@anymarket.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Join AnyMarket"}                                                       
2014-09-10T05:19:43.458693+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.9ms)                                                         
2014-09-10T05:19:43.564834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=2b72d511-c72a-4091-8f7b-c6a96be14b9d fwd="98.245.3.22
3" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=226ms status=302 bytes=1272                                                                                                            
2014-09-10T05:19:43.663161+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.245.3.223 at 2014-09-10 05:19:43 +0000                                                               
2014-09-10T05:19:43.822546+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (149.0ms)                                                         
2014-09-10T05:19:43.826212+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 122.7ms | ActiveRecord: 32.9ms)                                                           
2014-09-10T05:19:43.667650+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:19:43.825590+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_no_cc_alert.html.erb (0.3ms)                                                                            
2014-09-10T05:19:43.827152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=4146422c-eee3-4718-bcd3-ac57a3270cd9 fwd="98.245.3.223" dyn
o=web.1 connect=1ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=1324
```

And then once I click the confirm link:

```
2014-09-10T05:19:43.827152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=4146422c-eee3-4718-bcd3-ac57a3270cd9 fwd="98.245.3.223" dyn
o=web.1 connect=1ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=1324                                                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:20:09.309563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=1e871265-fe33-47a4-b141-e107fb516db3 fwd="54.247.188.179" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=432                                                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:20:47.054014+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=1b8ff5d7-4aa3-4a20-a16d-79531c4bf362 fwd="54.248.250.232" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=301 bytes=432                                                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:20:54.673266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=e728d60a-cb16-4de0-a093-44c7dcad1048 fwd="184.73.237.85" d
yno=web.1 connect=3ms service=3ms status=301 bytes=431                                                                                                                   
2014-09-10T05:21:09.238154+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=337c509a-4b15-45b8-a95e-5d9da765a594 fwd="98.245.3.223" dyn
o=web.1 connect=1ms service=102ms status=200 bytes=1292                                                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:21:09.147871+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML                                                                                  
2014-09-10T05:21:09.235638+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_no_cc_alert.html.erb (0.3ms)                                                                            
2014-09-10T05:21:09.142466+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.245.3.223 at 2014-09-10 05:21:09 +0000                                                               
2014-09-10T05:21:09.232445+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (77.5ms)                                                          
2014-09-10T05:21:09.236220+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 47.6ms | ActiveRecord: 37.2ms)                                                             
2014-09-10T05:21:39.043506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.anymarket.co request_id=47a3486a-a83c-4886-a774-0819d7652201 fwd="50.31.164.139" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=431
```

Comment: can you post heroku logs?

Comment: which command should I use? 'heroku logs' doesn't show much helpful

Comment: in your logs, can't see a request being sent to devise confirmation controller. You sure these are full logs?

Comment: What command should I use to get the full logs?

Comment: I used heroku logs --tail and that's what I got

Comment: heroku logs should have worked. Try to match the token in link with the one stored in database also try to recreate the problem in development, may be you'll find something useful because when you click on your link it should take you to devise confirmation controllers show action and in your logs i can't see that happening